# Multiple variables in for loops, Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I don't understand how does this code work. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to use ? and : in for loops? What do they mean?

```
var range = function(start, end, step) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; step > 1 || step === undefined ? i <= end : i >= end; step ? i = i + step : i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: [JavaScript conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing special about for loops. "?" is the [ternary operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
step === undefined ? i <= end : i >= end
```

evaluates to `i <= end` if step is undefined, otherwise to `i >= end`. Or with other words it gives the same result as

```
(function foo() {
    if (step === undefined) {
        return (i <= end); 
    } else {
        return (i >= end); 
    }
})()
```

The second use of the ? operator is more tricky as it manipulates the content of i as a side effect. That is the author of this code evaluates the variable step. If it is truthy the i will be advanced by step, otherwise it will be incremented.

Comment: So from what I understand I can use ternary operator as a shorthand for if statements? Is it better to use shorthand properties, or just use if..else?

Comment: @Punkdog it depends; use `?` operator for expressions (assigning variables, etc.) and `if` for statement (run this block of code or the other, no return value).

Answer (score 0):

That is just the [Conditional (Ternary) Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

It's almost shorthand for an if-else statement, in that:

```
return (boolean expression) ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
```

is the same as:

```
if (boolean expression) {
    return ifTrue;
} else {
    return ifFalse;
}
```

So in your for loop,

```
step === undefined ? i <= end : i >= end
```

means:

1. If step is undefined
2. The for loop condition (which normally looks like `i < length`) should be `i <= end`
3. otherwise (step is defined) the for loop condition should be `i >= end`